# Why the pointer's value changes in multi-thread malloc?

Tags: c, multithreading, malloc

1. Hi guys, I get a very odd problem here. Do u have any idea about the
   segmentation fault? Any advice would be appreciated! Thx in advance!

Test()

{

```
pMsg_node = found_bakup_msg_node();

if(pMsg_node != NULL) {
    Dprintf("#%s#%d %p\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, pMsg_node); 
    ret = cp_msg_node_data(pMsg_node, pMsg_next);
}
```

}

===================================================================

struct MSG_INFO* found_bakup_msg_node(void)
{
        struct MSG_INFO* msg_node = NULL;

```
    msg_node = (struct MSG_INFO*)malloc(sizeof(struct MSG_INFO));
    if(msg_node != NULL) {
            memset(msg_node, 0x0, sizeof(struct MSG_INFO));

            Dprintf("#%s# %p\n", __FUNCTION__,
                             msg_node);
    }

    return msg_node;
```

}

========================================================

---------------------------LOG 1--------------------------------

```
> header=0x923950    
>found_bakup_msg_node#alloc_bakup_count=1 0x7f6090032f70 //return from malloc() 
>cp_msg_list#561
> cp_msg_node_data#458   
>cp_msg_node_data#463 0xffffffff90032f70  0x923950  //notice here
>Segmentation fault
> robin@robin-desktop:/media/work/project/rcd$
```

--------------------------LOG 2 --------------------------------

```
 #cp_msg_list#566
#found_bakup_msg_node#alloc_bakup_count=180 **0x7fe6e000d5b0**
#cp_msg_node_data#464 **0xffffffffe000d5b0** 0x2154620
Segmentation fault
robin@robin-desktop:/media/work/project/rcd$
```

---

Comment: OS:
uname -a 
Linux robin-desktop 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:12:07 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 ......
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)

Comment: Stop casting malloc().  It's C, not C++.  It may even help you track down the bug.  Too many fragments to wade through it all, since we can't compile/test it as is.  If you can reduce the code down to a smaller piece and still have the segfault you might find it on your own quickly.  Since you are Linux, you likely should try -pthread instead of -lpthread as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the program under gdb? It usually shows why you got the segmentation fault, and it's useful in general to learn how to work with gdb.

Comment: Trying...,thanks bgeron!  And I guess memcpy data from addr 0x2154620  to addr 0xffffffffe000d5b0 cause the segmentation fault.

Comment: Fixed. It's because Test() calls the found_bakup_msg_node(void) before declare, so that the return value should be 32bit by default. While the return value > 32bit, system would autocomplete the value which bases on the highest bit, as 0x0000 0000 1111 1111 or 0xffff ffff 1111 1111.

Comment: @user2203111 If you found the error, post it as an answer to your question.

Comment: The solution is: Simply declare the api in the header before you call it, so that the caller will not auto complete the return address by default. This issues should not happen in 32 bit system.